# How to point to underlying class of <T> in generic factory

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting, abstract-factory

Got some vegetables going on:

```
public interface IVegetable
{

}

public class Potato : IVegetable
{

}

public class Onion : IVegetable
{

}
```

We'd focus on the onion and process it: I have single generic interface for a generic vegetable processor and one onion-specific:

```
public interface IVegetableProcessor<T> where T : IVegetable
{
    string GetColor(T vegetable);
}

public interface IOnionProcessor : IVegetableProcessor<Onion>
{
    void MakeCry(Onion onion);
}

public class OnionProcessor : IOnionProcessor
{
    public string GetColor(Onion onion)
    {
        return "Purple";
    }

    public void MakeCry(Onion onion)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{onion} made you cry!");
    }
}
```

As well as a generic factory:

```
interface IVegetableProcessorFactory
{
    IVegetableProcessor<T> GetVegetableProcessor<T>(T vegetable) where T : IVegetable;
}

internal class VegetableProcessorFactory : IVegetableProcessorFactory
{
    public IVegetableProcessor<T> GetVegetableProcessor<T>(T vegetable) where T : IVegetable
    {
        object processor = vegetable switch
        {
            Onion => new OnionProcessor(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Other vegetables not here yet")
        };

        return (IVegetableProcessor<T>)processor; //this will fail later
    }
}
```

And finally this does not work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var onion = new Onion() as IVegetable;
    var factory = new VegetableProcessorFactory();

    var processor = factory.GetVegetableProcessor(onion);

    Console.WriteLine(processor.GetColor(onion));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The error is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'OnionProcessor' to type 'IVegetableProcessor`1[Vegetables.Program+IVegetable]'.'
```

How to make it understand the underlying class of IVegetable and cast the processor to it's corresponding type?

Comment: `IVegetableProcessor<Onion>` is not instance of `IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable>` as there is no **covariance**

Comment: ```IVegetableProcessor<Onion>``` does inherit from ```IVegetableProcessor<T>```where T is ultimately an IVegetable so I thought it'd work... How to make this right?

Comment: *`IVegetableProcessor<Onion>` does inherit from `IVegetableProcessor<T>`* no... `IVegetableProcessor<Onion>` is `IVegetableProcessor<T>` where `T` is `Onion`... There is no inheritance

Comment: To solve a variance problem, you can 1) use more generics. In your case the caller would need to know they have an onion. 2) use more types. `interface IVegetableProcessor{} interface IVegetableProcessor<T>:IVegetableProcessor{}` so your `GetVegetableProcessor()` & `Main()` can use the simpler interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is already contravariant, but by casting your Onion instance to `IVegetable`, it is no longer able to be cast back to `IVetetableProcessor<T>` in your factory, because at that point you need `IVetetableProcessor<Onion>`, but what you have is a `IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable>`, and your interface is not covariant.

By simply removing your initial cast of `new Onion` to `IVegetable`, your code works as is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var onion = new Onion();
    var factory = new VegetableProcessorFactory();

    var processor = factory.GetVegetableProcessor(onion);

    Console.WriteLine(processor.GetColor(onion));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public interface IVegetable { }
public class Potato : IVegetable { }
public class Onion : IVegetable { }

public interface IVegetableProcessor<T> where T : IVegetable
{
    string GetColor(T vegetable);
}

public interface IOnionProcessor : IVegetableProcessor<Onion>
{
    void MakeCry();
}

public class OnionProcessor : IOnionProcessor
{
    public string GetColor(Onion vegetable)
    {
        return "Purple";
    }

    public void MakeCry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You cry now!");
    }
}

interface IVegetableProcessorFactory
{
    IVegetableProcessor<T> GetVegetableProcessor<T>(T vegetable) where T : IVegetable;
}

internal class VegetableProcessorFactory : IVegetableProcessorFactory
{
    public IVegetableProcessor<T> GetVegetableProcessor<T>(T vegetable) where T : IVegetable
    {
        var processor = vegetable switch
        {
            Onion => new OnionProcessor(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Other vegetables not here yet")
        };

        return (IVegetableProcessor<T>)processor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I specifically included this cast to make it look like a real-world scenario. What is I had an array if unsorted IVegetables to process? I would not know their actual types at compile time.

Comment: You have to bear the variance cost somewhere. You can't have variance both ways. If you'd prefer my other answer, that's fine as well. But then you have to cast in the implementing method.

Comment: Wont this crash at runtime on last line of factory? Oh you changed main too no problem.

Comment: @DavidL in other words there is no real benefit in using generics here as we'd have to cast anyway at some point?

Comment: It really depends on what you need the generics to DO, which isn't clear from your example. You cannot apply covariance and contravariance to the same method, which is fundamentally what you are running into. As a result, if you want to use generics, you are forced to make a choice of where express the opposite behavior of your contract via a cast.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have to cast in the first place is your hint that something is broken in your composition.  As Selvin mentioned in the comments, implementing `IVegetableProcessor<Onion>` is NOT the same thing as implementing `IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable>`.

Your processor interfaces should implement `IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable>` and take IVegetable instances, allowing contravariance for the input parameters:

```
public interface IVegetableProcessor<T> where T : IVegetable
{
    string GetColor(T vegetable);
}

public interface IOnionProcessor : IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable>
{
    void MakeCry();
}

public class OnionProcessor : IOnionProcessor
{
    public string GetColor(IVegetable vegetable)
    {
        return "Purple";
    }

    public void MakeCry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You cry now!");
    }
}

interface IVegetableProcessorFactory
{
    IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable> GetVegetableProcessor(IVegetable vegetable);
}

internal class VegetableProcessorFactory : IVegetableProcessorFactory
{
    public IVegetableProcessor<IVegetable> GetVegetableProcessor(IVegetable vegetable)
    {
        var processor = vegetable switch
        {
            Onion => new OnionProcessor(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"Other vegetables not here yet")
        };

        return processor;
    }
}
```

This correctly outputs "Purple" when run via:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var onion = new Onion();
    var factory = new VegetableProcessorFactory();

    var processor = factory.GetVegetableProcessor(onion);

    Console.WriteLine(processor.GetColor(onion));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but is it not confusing that with this approach method GetColor in OnionProcessor now gets IVegetable as a parameter and not an Onion? What if we wanted to get some onion-specific properties in this method? Then we'd have to cast and you told that casting hints to a broken design.

If I have to cast IVegetable to Onion in every method then I don't see any advantages of using generics at all!